# With custom view controller push transitions, how do I take a snapshot/screenshot of the "incoming" view controller with its navigation bar?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

This is driving me crazy. I want to take a screenshot of the incoming view controller, including the navigation bar (but not the status bar), so I can slide the full thing on top of the current view controller as the transition. However if I call `snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates` on the `toViewController.view` it doesn't have the navigation bar. If I call it on `[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow` it will include the navigation bar, but it's for the current view controller, not the incoming one. The same applies to `drawViewHierarchyInRect`.

How should I be doing this?